# Camera isn't working right. Roblox Studio Camera

Tags: lua, camera, roblox

We have got a problem with camera script, it isn't working right. I mean, camera works far not always. We don't know how to fix it. Camera's CFrame doesn't change. In output nothing gives about the camera. If the camera works randomly, then there has a way to fix it, right?

I just show, how is this script working.
[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yLJUdouS35jd9cWRJ8UI4SAWiKZ_ezW4/view?usp=share_link)

Local Script Code:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
local camera =  game.Workspace.CurrentCamera
camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
camera.CFrame = game.Workspace[script.Parent.Camera.Value.Name].CFrame
game:GetService("RunService").RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
    camera.CFrame = game.Workspace[script.Parent.Camera.Value.Name].CFrame
end)
```

I hope you can help us. I cannot post this issue in DevForumRoblox just because I haven't got enough rank up for that.
Thanks if you help us!

I have tried to use TextButton to call functions using MouseClicking, but it hasn't got any result.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the output?

Comment: No, I didn’t get any errors, and when I wrote in the print function, It wrote print in the function without problems.